# print specific line if it is matches with the line after it

Tags: linux, perl, bash, sed, awk

I have a log file containing the following info:

```
    <msisdn>37495989804</msisdn>
    <address>10.14.14.26</address>
    <msisdn>37495371855</msisdn>
    <address>10.14.0.172</address>
    <msisdn>37495989832</msisdn>
    <address>10.14.14.29</address>
    <msisdn>37495479810</msisdn>
    <address>10.14.1.11</address>
    <msisdn>37495429157</msisdn>
    <address>10.14.0.213</address>
    <msisdn>37495275824</msisdn>
    <msisdn>37495739176</msisdn>
    <address>10.14.2.86</address>
    <msisdn>37495479840</msisdn>
    <address>10.14.1.12</address>
    <msisdn>37495706059</msisdn>
    <msisdn>37495619889</msisdn>
    <address>10.14.1.198</address>
    <msisdn>37495574341</msisdn>
    <address>10.14.1.148</address>
    <msisdn>37495391624</msisdn>
    <address>10.14.0.188</address>
    <msisdn>37495989796</msisdn>
    <address>10.14.14.24</address>
    <msisdn>37495835940</msisdn>
    <address>10.14.2.164</address>
    <msisdn>37495743249</msisdn>
    <address>10.14.2.94</address>
    <msisdn>37495674117</msisdn>
    <address>10.14.1.236</address>
    <msisdn>37495754536</msisdn>
    <address>10.14.2.120</address>
    <msisdn>37495576434</msisdn>
    <msisdn>37495823889</msisdn>
    <address>10.14.2.159</address>
```

There are some lines where the 'msisdn' line is not followed by an 'address' line, like this:

```
<msisdn>37495576434</msisdn>
<msisdn>37495823889</msisdn>
```

I would like to write a script which will output only the lines ('msisdn' lines), that aren't followed by 'address'. Expected output:

```
<msisdn>37495275824</msisdn>
<msisdn>37495706059</msisdn>
<msisdn>37495576434</msisdn>
```

If it will be smth with awk/sed, it will be perfect.
Thanks.

Comment: `I need to have script` -- ok sir, what is the deadline?

Comment: It will be perfect to have it within 2 hours... :)

Comment: Hmm.. bonus points for using sed/awk -- `If it will be smth with awk/sed, it will be perfect`

Comment: You seem to be new to SO.  You might see how questions are closed and how downvotes work.

Comment: @devnull Sorry but I still can't stop laughing at his comment.

Comment: @JS웃 And I can't stop laughing to see 4 different answers within 2 hours

Answer (score 2):

One way with `awk`:

```
awk '/address/{p=0}p{print a;p=0}/msisdn/{a=$0;p=1}' log
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use pcregrep to match next line is not adddress and use awk show it

```
pcregrep -M '(.*</msisdn>)\n.*<msi' | awk 'NR % 2 == 1'
```

Comment: Is not worked correctly with pcregrep:
<msisdn>37495648908</msisdn>
<address>10.14.1.226</address>
<msisdn>37495733387</msisdn>
<address>10.14.0.73</address>
<address>10.14.1.154</address>
<msisdn>37495203739</msisdn>
<address>10.14.3.41</address>
<msisdn>37495241193</msisdn>
<msisdn>37495374976</msisdn>
<msisdn>37495668028</msisdn>
<msisdn>37495380414</msisdn>
<msisdn>37495697931</msisdn>
<address>10.14.2.102</address>
<msisdn>37495749327</msisdn>
<address>10.14.2.88</address>
<msisdn>37495770847</msisdn>
<address>10.14.0.75</address>
<msisdn>37495480837</msisdn>

Comment: I use your example data and it works `cat ~/tmp/ss | pcregrep -M '(.*</msisdn>)\n.*<msi' | awk 'NR % 2 == 1'` i get `<msisdn>37495275824</msisdn>
    <msisdn>37495706059</msisdn>
    <msisdn>37495576434</msisdn>`

Comment: or just use other answer, it is shorter, although I don't understand, I tested it and worked

Comment: @WilliamHerry What I am doing is, looking for lines with `/msisdn/` and when seen capture the line in variable `a` and set another variable `p` to `1`. If the next line is `/address/` then i reset `p` to `0` since that's not what OP is looking for. However, if next line is not `/address/` then the `p{..}` gets triggered and the `msisdn` captured earlier is printed out.

Comment: What is the problem, that I have checked the both commands and then compared them - the result is different... So I don't know now which command is the right...

Comment: @user37033 Run it on a smaller data set to which you know the output. Then you can compare which output you want and go with that. BTW the output from William's solution matches to my output. So there could be an issue with your real data which might not be an accurate representation of sample data.

Comment: Thanks dears for quick help :)
Also if possible please give me the same in Perl.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r '$!N;/(<msisdn>).*\n.*\1/P;D' file
```

This reads 2 lines into the pattern space and trys to match the pattern `<msisdn>` in both the 2 lines. If the pattern matchs it prints out the first line. The first line is then deleted and the process begins again, however since the pattern space contains the second line (now the first), the automatic reading of a line is forgone and process begins as of `$!N`.

Answer (score 0):

Perl has its own way to do this:

```
perl -lne 'if($prev && $_!~/\./){print $prev}unless(/\./){$prev=$_}else{undef $prev}' your_file
```

Tested Below:

```
> perl -lne 'if($prev && $_!~/\./){print $prev}unless(/\./){$prev=$_}else{undef $prev}' temp
<msisdn>37495275824</msisdn>
<msisdn>37495706059</msisdn>
<msisdn>37495576434</msisdn>
>
```